# Iterating through $F^n/S_m$ for $m<n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a vector space $F^n$ for some finite field $F$, and I would like to iterate through the orbits of the action of $G$ on this space, where $G$ is a particular embedding of $S_m$ in $S_n$. In case it's not clear, the action I'm referring to is a permutation of the indices of the vector space. The construction of the object $\mathbb{R}^n/S_n$ gives an orbifold, so the idea is not entirely out of left field. The definition of an orbifold requires a Hausdorff space, however, so I don't see it applying to finite fields.

Obviously if $m=n$ I can just iterate through the number of possibilities with $n_i$ coordinates that are $f_i$ (where $F=\{f_i\}$) such that $\sum n_i = n$, and that gives one element from each orbit as desired. But if $m<n$ this no longer works.

For some embeddings of $S_m$ in $S_n$ this is still not hard: for example, take the map $\phi([i_1,\dots,i_m]) = [i_1,\dots,i_m,m+1,\dots,n]$. In this case I can simply do the procedure described above with the first $m$ indices, and then let the rest of the indices take any values. Embeddings that are less simple become less obvious. Given an injective homomorphism $\phi:S_m\to S_n$ defining the embedding, is there a way to iterate through the orbits of the action of $\phi(S_m)$ on $F^n$ without iterating through all of $F^n$ to see an element is already in a found orbit? My first thought is to somehow transform this into the simple embedding described above and then transform it back, but the fact that $\phi$ doesn't have an inverse makes this tough, I don't see it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not surprising that I could not find a way to transform it into a simpler embedding. Taking $n=6, m=4, F=F_3$, the embedding $\phi_1([i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4])=[i_1,i_2,i_3,i_4,5,6]$ gives a subgroup of $S_6$ isomorphic to $S_4$ whose action on $F_3^6$ has 135 orbits, while the embedding $\phi_2$ defined by how it maps the generators of $S_4$

$\phi_2([2,1,3,4])=[1,4,5,2,3,6]$,

$\phi_2([2,3,4,1])=[4,5,1,6,2,3]$,

gives a subgroup of $S_6$ isomorphic to $S_4$ whose action on $F_3^6$ has 66 orbits. I would've thought that isomorphic subgroups inheriting the action from the parent group would have the same number of orbits, but apparently that is not so.